# Apache Shiro + MySQL database on Docker container: "Communications link failure"

Tags: mysql, docker, jakarta-ee, shiro

I'm trying to link Apache Shiro with a MySQL database located on a local docker container.

Using clients such as Sequel Pro or IntelliJ built-in client, I can connect to the db using the following configuration:

```
hostname = 127.0.0.1 ("localhost" works too)
port = 13306
user = root
password = admin
database = UNIHUB_DB
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:13306/UNIHUB_DB
```

Now, using the following Shiro.ini configuration:

```
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT passwd from USERS where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role from USERS where username = ?

ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.port = 13306
ds.user = root
ds.password = admin
ds.databaseName = UNIHUB_DB
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds
```

it always fail with stacktrace:

```
08:59:04,202 ERROR [org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm] (default task-1) There was a SQL error while authenticating user [{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}]: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:590)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:57)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:139)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(JdbcRealm.java:215)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
    at ch.unihub.business.service.AuthServiceRs.login(AuthServiceRs.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at ch.unihub.business.service.AuthServiceRs$$$view24.login(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:511)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:366)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:361)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:368)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:313)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:441)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:361)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1726)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
    ... 128 more
```

I've tried different configurations for Shiro, such as replacing "localhost" by "127.0.01", "192.168.1.5", using `ds.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:13306/UNIHUB_DB`, `ds.port = 3306`, but nothing will do..

**EDIT**

Ok, so it works using this configuration instead:

```
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceName = UNIHUBDS
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds
```

with `UNIHUBDS` being a jta data soure defined in a `persistence.xml` file. 
I still don't understand why it wouldn't work with the previous configuration though.

Comment: Is WildFly also in a docker container?

Comment: Yes exactly @SteveC

Comment: What is the name of your mysql docker container?

Comment: `(CONTAINER ID,        IMAGE,               COMMAND,                  CREATED,             STATUS,              PORTS,                                                                       NAMES) = (aa35c76dff58,        unihub-mysql,        "docker-entrypoint.s…",   2 hours ago,         Up 2 hours,          0.0.0.0:13306->3306/tcp,                                                     boring_meitner)`